# Chrome Extension - Process output with a hosted PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension I've developed that reads and parses HTML contents into a CSV file.
This part works great, and the user is able to download the file.

What I want to do at this point, is find a way to send that data directly to a MySQL database.

I know that a chrome extension cannot run PHP (obviously).  I do however have access to a hosted web server to which I can upload custom PHP scripts.

Is there any way to send my parsed data directly to a hosted PHP script which will process the data and then send the data to a MySQL database on the same server?

Everything I've researched thus far has resulted in "chrome extensions cannot run PHP scripts" . . .

Thanks for your help!

Edit:  One option I was thinking of would be to inject HTML hidden fields with values of my data, and then use javascript to POST the data to the PHP URL . . . . Would that be an option?  Can chrome extensions inject hidden fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely make a POST method HTTP request to a server from a chrome extension. It doesn't require any kind of hack to accomplish this. With native JavaScript use the 'POST' method to an XMLHttpRequest or with a library like jQuery just make a `$.post` request.

A couple of things:

**You're going to want to use HTTPS, so get an SSL certificate for your server/domain**. If you are parsing any kind of website content on an HTTPS protected page and sending that in the clear text to your own server you are doing A Very Bad Thing. Do Not Do That.

**Make sure you tell your users that you are doing this**. Some/Most people may not want that.

Use a content script to grab the content from the DOM. Pass it to your extensions background script using postMessage message passing.

Make the POST request from your background script.

You will need to update your manifest.json to have permissions to the URLs you want to inject the content into, and permissions to make the POST request to your server's domain. Users will have to see and approve these permissions, but they will not know what you are doing, so be sure to tell them.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this information!  The data being parsed in not sensitive in anyway, but thanks for the suggestions regarding security!  The extension is just a school project, so the only users will be me and my team members.